# Calculating sum of array contents and list it based on condition met

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, vba

The following code lists array contents of `v(v1(i))` in the active cell and its offsets. I want to put a condition before listing. I want to check sum of all the values in the `v1` array before listing and if the sum is `>=5` and `<=10` then only list it. How can I achieve this?

```
v1 = Split(Replace(Trim(s), "'", ""), " ")
For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = v(v1(i))
Next
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
v1 = Split(Replace(Trim(s), "'", ""), " ")
For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
    t = t + Val(v1(i))
Next i
If t >= 5 And t <= 10 Then
    For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = v(v1(i))
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: instead of having two for loops rounds, is there a way to check the sum of the array in one command? I was trying `application.worksheetfuntions.sum` but unable to get the sum of all values `of v(v1())`

Comment: No. You need to loop through all values to get their total. And you can't start writing the first value before you have calculated the total. The `Split` function returns an array of strings which isn't optimal for processing numbers, but I think you are stuck with strings because of the origin of the data in a CSV file.

Comment: If you could make v1 into a Variant you might be able to write it to the sheet with one command avoiding the second loop but not the first.

Comment: well.. unfortunately I cannot edit the code and cannot change the type of v1. May be I need to review the structure of my rawdata. Thanks for your help